# What is the name of this brown, "flat hat", fungus?

Tags: species-identification, mycology

I've seen this in October 2016 on Corsica (Island of France):

[image]

See https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Gr-20-petra-piana-to-onda-08.jpg for more images and higher resolutions.

Comment: feels like it could be some sort of Amanita. i only see that one image in your link, are there more from other angles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty sure (but not 100% certain) that it is a [Amanita porphyria bk9845](http://www.hlasek.com/amanita_porphyria.html), which in german is called a "Porphyrbrauner Wulstling"

> Cap: 3-12 cm; convex, becoming broadly convex, often with a central bump; sticky at first or when wet; bald; appearing streaked radially; the margin not prominently lined; grayish brown to brown or purplish brown; often with scattered gray to purplish gray warts or patches.

[image]

*Source:*

- [amanita porphyria](http://www.mushroomexpert.com/amanita_porphyria.html)